# How to show the console in a Swift Playground Book?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground

I'm creating a Swift Playground Book with Xcode, using [Apple's Swift Playgrounds Author Template](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=Swift%20Playgrounds%20Author%20Template).

Now I want my students who will work with this playground book to have a console, so they can use `print` statements for debugging.

In playground books provided by Apple, there is usually a button to open the console in the lower-right corner:

[image: Apple Playground Screenshot]

However, when I open my own Playground Book with Swift Playgrounds, there is no console button:

[image: Screenshot of my own Playground Book]

**How can I get a console in my Playground Book?**

Comment: Check if the "Show Console" toggle button is enabled.

Comment: There is no "Show Console" toggle button. That's my problem.

Comment: There is if you tap on the 'speedometer' icon

Comment: Ah! That button didn't appear either before I set the Version to 8.0 in the Manifest.plist.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution.

You have to set the `Version` key in the Playground Book's `Manifest.plist` file to version `8.0` (or above I guess).

[image: Property List Editor in Xcode]

or when editing the file's source code directly:

```
<key>Version</key>
<string>8.0</string>
```

For no apparent reason, Apple doesn't provide a Swift Playgrounds Author Template for the latest stable Xcode version (13.4) at this time (which is trouble in itself as you have to download the matching Swift toolchain to even build that template), so I used the newest template available instead which is for Xcode 13.2. This template has the `Version` set to `7.0` and it seems like this Playground version does not support the console yet.